# A word for "a means of getting a job over reliable candidates"

Tags: word-request

I want the word that means "a means of getting a job over reliable candidates", but I'm going to explain it here again in an example.

The example: If X and Y applied to a job, and X happened to have a relative that works in the company they applied to it, while Y knows no one in that company, but he has very high qualifications over X. However, X got the job nonetheless since he had a _____.

X could have got the job by other means like he knows the manager there, for example. Thus, it is not only relatives related.

I thought of "means" and "intermediate" but the results I got didn't confirm my thoughts.

[Means](https://www.google.ps/search?ei=SBBLXMubLIrYwQK-x7aQDw&q=Means+in+the+job+industry&oq=Means+in+the+job+industry&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3...3559.5310..6303...0.0..0.189.345.0j2......0....1.........0i71.MA_95iQ0FXg)

[Intermediate](https://www.google.ps/search?ei=kBBLXNiYJdLMwAKOpJLgDg&q=intermediates+in+the+job+industry&oq=intermediates+in+the+job+industry&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3...408101.413387..414265...0.0..0.250.3216.0j14j4....2..0....1.........0i71j0i8i30j0i8i7i30j30i10.eGR3aV3sUAA)

Comment: I think you were looking for *means*, not *mean*, but it takes some doing to get to the relevant definitions on web-based dictionary pages.  In this case *intermediate* is not at all synonymous.  See [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/means), under the 'Noun' section, sub-definition 2: "**means** *plural in form but singular or plural in construction* : something useful or helpful to a desired end."

Comment: I have searched for their meanings on web dictionaries. I just didn't add that part in my question as their meanings were nothing like what I intend. My choice for those two words was based on a literal translation from my native language. However, you are right about "means", I should have searched more deeply.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could say that X had an ***[in](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in)***:

> **in** *noun*
>     2: influence, pull
>  • enjoyed some sort of *in* with the commandant
> — *Henriette Roosenburg*
>   <sub>*definition from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in)*</sub>

Comment: This is definitely the best current answer that encompasses means other than "I know someone at the company", such as bribing the interviewer.

Answer (score 18):

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/connection), definition #6, you can use the word **connection**:

> 6. A person, especially one of influence or importance, with whom one is associated, as by kinship or common interests: used her connections to land a job.

Consequently,

> X used their connections to land the job.

Comment: Sometimes satirically termed "Vitamin C".

Answer (score 17):

> X got the job due to nepotism.

"Nepotism" indicates favoritism due to a familial relationship. If some other relationship is involved

> X got the job due to favoritism.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is "the inside track."

> **inside track** *noun*
>
> an advantageous competitive position
>
> Example: "The owner's son has the inside track for the job."

From [Merriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inside%20track#examples)

The advantage of having the inside track doesn't necessarily need to be a connection or relationship to a particular person. It could also be better qualifications, familiarity with an institution or system, or something else that puts a person in a better position than someone they're competing with. According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary,](https://www.etymonline.com/word/inside#etymonline_v_9328) the meaning comes from horse racing, where the horse on the inside part of a curved track has to travel a shorter distance on each lap than the horses further away from the center.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single word, but "friend at court" suggests that the relative at the company, while not a decision maker themselves, promoted them over the more qualified candidate.

Answer (score 1):

> X got the job nonetheless since he had **a leg up** on Y.

Or,

> X got the job nonetheless since he had the favor of the employers (political influence)

Also,

> X got the job nonetheless due to politics

*(Politics is here used in opposition to merits).*